# Type error on RetryWhen() with delay

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) and then adding this line:

```
.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
```

To my `Transformer`, but it triggers a compilation error:

> error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>   (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
>   Observable cannot be converted to Publisher)
>   where R,T are type-variables:
>   R extends Object declared in method flatMap(Function>)
>   T extends Object declared in class Flowable

And the squiggly lines below `error -> Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` say:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Observable conforms to Publisher

What am I doing wrong? What's missing for this to work as in the example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Please check the signatures of operators so that you are using the right types: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#base-class-vs-base-type

[JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

```java
public final Single<T> retryWhen(
    Function<? super Flowable<Throwable>,? extends Publisher<?>> handler)
```

> Because this tutorial uses Observable.timer with no issues.

That tutorial predates RxJava 2. In fact, the Javadoc linked above contains an example with `Flowable.timer()`:

```java
Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("subscribing"))
.map(v -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
.retryWhen(errors -> {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    return errors
              .takeWhile(e -> counter.getAndIncrement() != 3)
              .flatMap(e -> {
                  System.out.println("delay retry by " + counter.get() + " second(s)");
//                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                  return Flowable.timer(counter.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              });
})
.blockingGet();
```

> is this something only related to Single

`retryWhen` and `repeatWhen` use `Publisher` as the redo signal by design so that we can leverage backpressure to only ask for one such redo signal at a time. With `Observable`, there is a chance a handler would simply dump a lot of signals at once and the operators may behave unexpectedly.

Comment: I saw that example on the documentations, but I find it over complicated and decided that for now I just wanted a fixed delay. I am new to Rx so I am trying to get familiar with the simple things first. Many thanks!

Comment: @akarnokd how do you go about returning an Error when you have retried the maximum number of times? Flowable.error(new RunTimeException("")) will not compile

Comment: @hector perhaps add type arguments like `Flowable.<YourType>error()`.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks for your suggestion. It resolved my compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using `Flowable.timer()` instead of `Observable.timer` fixes this, maybe it's something only related to `Single`?